# Given $0<x<y$, find rational number $q$ so that $0< q <x<y< 1/q$.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

> For all $0<x<y$ there exist a rational $q$ such that $0<q<x<y<1/q$.

How can I prove this? I suppose that I should use the statement that for every pair of real numbers there exists rational between them. Geometrically speaking, I understand what it says. Always we can find a small rational number $q$ such that $1/q$ become larger than any number we want. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: if $x =0.123421123$, and $y = 1.521341312$, what can you pick $q$ to be?

Comment: Some q very very small for example q=0,000000001

Comment: Think about why that works and how you can extend this intuition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: There is a positive integer $n>y$, and there is a positive integer $m$ such that $\frac1m<x$. Can you do anything useful with $\max\{m,n\}$?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, the Archimedes property is the perfect tool.

Comment: @KonstantinosDimoglou: You’re welcome.